# Make Menu Template Dynamic

Tags: php, jquery

I'm currently developing a website and decided to have the menus to be written in a separate file.

Currently I have a php page holding the menu list called menu.php

```
<?php
$menu='<div class="headMenu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="transaction.php"><span>Transaction</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="schedule.php"><span>Schedule</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="book.php"><span>Book</span></a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>';
     echo $menu;
  ?>
```

Whenever you enter the Transaction Page, the distinct code for that page is

```
<li class="active"><a href="transaction.php"><span>Transaction</span></a></li>
```

and same as the other pages,

I'm thinking this can be done in jquery using its .addClass() method, but I have no idea of passing variables from one page to the separate page holding the menu written in php

Comment: Do you mean you need to add class 'active' for the clicked link.that is if you clicked home link,home link will get the class as active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to do a function in `menu.php` that returns a `string` containing menu with "activated" page?
If I understand your question correctly, this would be helpfull:

```
    <?php
    function renderMenu($site){
      $menu='<div class="headMenu">
        <ul>
          <li '. ($site=="index.php"?'class="active"':'') .'><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
          //etc...
         </ul>
       </div>';
      return $menu;
    ?>
```

And then in your main script:

```
    echo renderMenu(__FILE__);
```

Comment: In case of the book.php, the code will goes like this right? `<?php include('menu.php');
  echo renderMenu('book.php');
  ?>` but it didnt applied the class

Comment: Have you changed a condition to: `($site=="book.php"?'class="active"':'')` ?
I have corrected mistake in my post and added a `space` after `<li`.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't saw it too. Thanks